# Unet Medical Image- Prediction Mask not getting displayed

Tags: python, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation, medical-imaging, unet-neural-network

I am trying to implement Unet based segmentation for Medical Histopathology classification for single class problem. I get the loss and accuracy of the model but predicted masks are not getting displayed at all. I am using Batch Size =32, Adam optimizer with 0.0001 learning rate and Sigmoid activation function. Please help.

```
def VisualizeResults(index):
    img = X_valid[index]
    img = img[np.newaxis, ...]
    pred_y = unet.predict(img)
    pred_mask = tf.argmax(pred_y[0], axis=-1)
    pred_mask = pred_mask[..., tf.newaxis]
    fig, arr = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 15))
    arr[0].imshow(X_valid[index])
    arr[0].set_title('Processed Image')
    arr[1].imshow(y_valid[index,:,:,0])
    arr[1].set_title('Actual Masked Image ')
    arr[2].imshow(pred_mask[:,:,0])
    arr[2].set_title('Predicted Masked Image ')

    # Add any index to contrast the predicted mask with actual mask
    index =13
    VisualizeResults(index)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRsfc.png)

Comment: To clarify, are you getting non zero values in your predicted mask and it's just not being plotted or are your masks all being returned as all zeroes?

Comment: @JesseSealand I am not sure as I am new to python but I think I get non zero values in the predicted mask and they are not plotted.